# Modx(Revolution) search function for FAQs

Tags: search, modx-revolution, extras

I'm trying to implement a search for my FAQs page. I'm using the modx extras FAQ Manager and SimpleSearch. SimpleSearch works quite well if you're searching modx resources, but the problem I've run into is how to search a database table for example the FAQ Manager table where the content is not tied to a resource. Is this possible?

I've noticed that SimpleSearch has a &customPackages property, but I can't seem to get it to work. If someone could show me an example of how to use simple search in conjunction with FAQ Manager, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search in a custom package through AdvSearch with a custom queryhook: http://www.revo.wangba.fr/custom-package-dvd-shop/

and the corresponding snippet since the link doesn't seem to work: http://www.revo.wangba.fr/assets/files/advsearch/queryhook/dvdqhook.snippet.txt

Comment: I ended up writing my own script, but this is good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the advanced search package to search database tables: http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/advsearch